# how to render stream file which has mimetype "text/html" or 'text/plain' in JSF panel

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on JSF2.2 and Primefaces 5.1, in my project have a servlet which update response outputstream, I call that servlet in JSF to render PDF like follows

```
<c:when test="#{documentBean.docType == 'application/pdf'}">
    <p:media value="/filePreview?id=#{searchBean.selectedID}" player="pdf" width="100%" height="300"/>          
</c:when>
```

which is working fine for me but I have other file which have mimetype like `text/plain` and `text/html` for that `<p:media>` tag is not working for all browsers.

Is there any way to render this type of file in JSF 2.2 or in primefaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this like following which is working for me, I hope this will help others too.

**NOTE:** ifram also work for "text/plain" and other image types

```
<c:when test="#{documentBean.docType == 'text/html'}">
    <iframe src="/filePreview?id=#{searchBean.selectedID}" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>              
</c:when>
```

Answer (score -1):

java for string you need use equal

try below code

```
<c:when test="#{documentBean.docType eq 'application/pdf'}">
    <p:media value="/filePreview?id=#{searchBean.selectedID}" player="pdf" width="100%" height="300"/>          
</c:when>
```

or

```
<c:when test="#{documentBean.docType.equal('application/pdf')}">
    <p:media value="/filePreview?id=#{searchBean.selectedID}" player="pdf" width="100%" height="300"/>          
</c:when>
```

Comment: <c:when> is working fine in my code, I want to know how can i reander other file which is not PDF but text or html